# What happens to food I don't digest before the day is over?

Tags: the-world-ends-with-you

One of the many (many) mechanics presented in the *World Ends with You* is the idea of eating and digesting food. Food items give an immediate benefit upon consumption (I've only seen sync % increases so far) and an additional one when fully digested.

Each food is takes a certain amount of "bytes" to fully digest, where one byte is equivalent to one round of combat. Seeing how there is a maximal amount of bytes that can be taken per day, it would be a shame not to use them all up (as the counter is reset, and you miss out on the potential bonuses you would have gotten).

My question is, what happens to food I've only partially digested when the day is over? Let's say I eat something that takes 10 bytes to digest, and then I only fight 5 groups of enemies before the day ends. I still have 5 more bytes to go before receiving that food item's digestion bonus. Do I simply miss out on the bonus? Do the remaining 5 bytes carry over to the next day, counting towards its limit? Something else?

Comment: The gray squares will disappear on a daily basis in real time. Note that SIX squares will ALWAYS remain, so as long as a food is six bytes or less, you can eat as much as you want.

Comment: @Krazer Oh, then the game was referring to actual days in the real world. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfinished food carries over to the next day, and will take up bytes on the next day.

The sync increase starts when you start eating the food.  The bonus (such as HP or DEF +) is awarded when the food is finished. Even if it takes you two days to eat the food, you'll still get the bonus when it's done.

All of the above is true until you get an Hollow Leg sticker, which allows you to eat 24 byte foods, and removes the daily byte cap.